# Bootstrap padding between columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm working on a page for a friend ( http://jojorules.com/index.php/our-pillows/ ) and I have 4 rows, with 3 columns each. Each column needs to have 80px of space between eachother, HOWEVER, the first and last column of each row needs to align with the logo/navbar links (indicated by the red lines on the image at the bottom).

Where I want the 80px spacing is indicated by the blue line/text in the image at the bottom as well.

These padding will only be on desktop, which I will add later, but I've been having issues coming up with a clean way that works well, and sticks with those red line alignments.

[image]

Comment: Why use bootstrap grid when you don't use the grid? You can always uncheck the grid when downloading bootstrap and make you own.

Comment: If you don't need exactly 80px, try using col-md-offset.

Comment: You should consider removing the see-through stuff on that page also! It looks messy with all that text under. http://s11.postimg.org/85a56d16b/baddesign.png

Comment: @chrisv Yeah I removed it tonight, just haven't pushed the changes to the dev server yet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the space between the columns remove left padding of first column and right padding of last column to align the content with navbar.

and to make the 80px work use this snippet (Assuming you are using `col-md-4`):

```
.col-md-4:first-child { padding-left: 0; padding-right: 40px; }
.col-md-4:last-child { padding-right: 0; padding-left: 40px; }
.col-md-4:nth-child(2) { padding-right: 40px; padding-left: 40px; }
```

**Note**: To make the text on right column to be exactly aligned with navbar, You must use `text-align: justify` in order to force the text for alignment.

Comment: Perfect, and ty for the text-align bit too :) Just what I was looking for